# past simple and present perfect

Tags: grammar, word-usage, meaning, past-tense, present-perfect

Question : I’m sorry that I ______(not raise) the curtain,but I will do it now.

--The answer is ***haven't raised*** . Can I say *did't raise* ? why?

Thanks

Comment: _Didn't raise_ would also fit, although, if the apology is in response to a  complaint about present conditions (e.g. the room being dark), _haven't raised_ might be more appropriate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When should I use "didn't" instead of "haven't"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/385/when-should-i-use-didnt-instead-of-havent) Also [“I didn't do it” vs “I haven't done it” - When do you use which?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/221116/i-didnt-do-it-vs-i-havent-done-it-when-do-you-use-which) and [I haven't noticed that vs. I didn't notice that](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/202887/i-havent-noticed-that-vs-i-didnt-notice-that), among others.

Answer (score 1):

The present perfect is used when there is a present effect or consequence, in this case the curtains are still closed and therefore the room is dark or stuffy or whatever. So the curtains being closed is somehow relevant to now. I personally find closed curtains during the day quite depressing, for example.

With the past simple there is no present effect, it is only about the past, there is no relevance to the present. If you add an adverb of time, like "this morning" when it is now afternoon, the past simple is fine.